# Create a hub for HTTP requests

Tags: command-line, bash

I am a very newbie in ubuntu and in computer programming in general.
I would like to create a hub which receives http requests from a server and sends it to an other machine. So my question is how can I write a script in bash which detects http requests from a specific web server ?

I only know how to do GET and POST requests with command line (thanks to curl command). And I would like to not use any other softwares to write the script except in bash.

I hope you can bring me some answers, I don't even know weather it is possible to do all those things.

Thank you very much.

Comment: That is called a webserver, I think. Look at apache or any other webserver of choice. Then look how to redirect requests in that webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a huge bash programmer, but a Google search resulted in ***shinatra.sh*** which is a "*bash web server in 5 lines*".  You may be able to adapt it to address your needs.  I found the information here: https://github.com/benrady/shinatra

The solution uses netcat (nc) to listen on a port for a request, and then do something.  Specific documentation on nc is available by typing ***man nc*** on Ubuntu at the terminal.  But you can also read it online here: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/nc.htm

Comment: Thank you so much i will take the time to look at it !

Comment: I think that's exactly what I was looking for, ofcourse the script will be modified to fit my requirements but the script provides a solid base to start. Thank you so much !